# django-admin startproject myworld cannot work on mac

Tags: python, django, pip, backend, virtualenv

I am learning django but stuck at beginning of start project as below in terminal:
kevinlin@kevindeMacBook-Pro ~ % django-admin startproject myworld
kevinlin@kevindeMacBook-Pro ~ %

I have installed python but version 2.7 shown on terminal, 3.10 version shown on python shell. I am wondering if the issue is caused by running version 2.7 on terminal ?

kevinlin@kevindeMacBook-Pro ~ % python --version
Python 2.7.18

Python 3.10.7 (v3.10.7:6cc6b13308, Sep  5 2022, 14:02:52)

I have checked all of pip/django/virtlenv have been installed.

I have tried to search solutions on google and here but cannot solve the issue.

Comment: install django version4 and python version 3.10 and then try to create project

Comment: yes installed django4 and python3 but still cannot work to create project.                       
kevinlin@kevindeMacBook-Pro ~ % django-admin --version
4.1.3

Answer (score 0):

The python version is shown is the globally installed python in Mac. Before running the python commands activate the virtualenv.

Creating virtual env:

```
python3 -m venv tutorial-env
```

Activating virtualenv:

```
source tutorial-env/bin/activate
```

Check the python version after that:

```
python --version
```

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments

Comment: I follow it and show python3 on terminal but close/reopen terminal and the version python2 shown on terminal. it means i need to activate the virtualenv each time while running django ?

Comment: Yes you have to activate each time you work on a project. It is like you have multiple virtual environments for each project with different dependencies and you activate whichever when you need for the project. After activating it all the dependencies you install sit inside it separately.